# JSON.stringify in response option of cy.route is not working

Tags: reactjs, integration-testing, cypress

I'm currently writing tests on Cypress for an application writen in react and using redux and redux-saga. For one of my tests, I'm trying to stub a request and returning a response that the code is expecting to be an 'stringified' array by JSON so it can be parsed later.

I've tried to specify a response in the cy.route() command using JSON.stringify([desiredResponse]) but that is not working, response keeps being kind of parsed by Cypress or some other middleware before getting to the saga.

I've also tried to intercept the response in the onResponse option but seems to me like that's being executed once the response was delivered (not sure about this, made a couple of vague tests only)

```
// This is how my cy.route() config looks like
cy.route({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'someUrl',
  response: JSON.stringify([myResponse]),
});
```

And in my saga:

```
// I call the url via axios and immediately after I try to parse it 
try {
  const parsed = JSON.parse(response.data);
} catch (err) {
  const parsed = [];
}
```

I would expect my response in the saga to be something like: "[myResponse]" but I got the raw array instead

Comment: Luis? Have you resolved it? Could you share any insights?

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity: have you tried avoiding to wrap `[myResponse]` into `JSON.stringify()`?

Something like

```
cy.route({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'someUrl',
  response: [myResponse],
});
```

Anyway: in my app, with your exact situation, my only difference with your code is that I leverage the [Cypress fixtures](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture.html#Syntax) .

Could you share a simple GitHub repo with your simplified code?